# getting "bash: /etc/profile [...] No such file or directory" message when starting up a new terminal window

Tags: rvm, bash

> Last login: Wed Feb 27 22:38:32 on ttys003
>   -bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
>   -bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
>   Williams-MacBook-Pro:~ william$

I think this has something to do with an rvm-installation going wrong sometime in the past, but I can't seem to fix the error that shows up everytime i open up a new terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to cd to /etc/profile and comment out the two lines that was causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to cd to /etc and to modify the profile file.

The previous answer to cd /etc/profile didn't work as on my Mac, "profile" is a file and not a directory.